# Every time Xcode updates and a new version is released I get an "exit code 1" error for my react native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I use yarn iOS to run my app on an Xcode simulation.

The new  Xcode 15.0 Release 15A240d was on  18 Sep 2023 and after that my project started to give me an error and I am unable to run yarn iOS and see my app load.

I have done the following already:

yarn install
cd ios
pod install

npm cache clean -f
npm install -g react-native

sudo gem install cocoapods
npm install -g @react-native-community/cli

rm -rf ios/Pods && rm -rf ios/build && cd ios && pod install && cd ../ && rm -rf node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn install

But still get the same code error.